# When I am logged into one of my many AWS EKS Custers' through my CLI, it signs me out at various times around 1 hour

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am on a Macbook Pro M1 and using a number of services to connect to my AWS EKS Clusters:

- `aws-vault`
- `aws-cli`
- kubeconfig script

When accessing any EKS Cluster, I can sign into successfully but I am signed out of inactivity around an hour. Is it possible to sign me out after a number of hours other than signing me out every hour? Would appreciate any help on this issue.

Comment: This is usually configured at the IAM policy level, with sessions defaulting to 1 hour: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/userguide/howtosessionduration.html

Comment: @wkl Oh this makes perfect sense. Short and simple. I thought the same. Thanks for the help! Going to check this out.